# How to get real time audio data from raspberry pi to simulink and apply real time signal processing

Tags: raspberry-pi, signal-processing, simulink, audio-recording

I am facing a problem with getting live (real time) audio data from raspberry pi to simulink. 
I want to get the data continuously from the microphone that  is connected the raspberry pi and process it in simulink continuously too. 
I am using the ALSA  Audio Capture block but its not working for me.
Anyone tried this before and may help please?
Thank you.

Comment: What is not working? Please describe your problem.

Comment: You might be interested to read the following: "How to use Rpi python to control PCM1802 24-bit HiFi stereo ADC and MAX4466 microphone amplifier?":
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/107778/how-to-use-rpi-python-to-control-pcm1802-24-bit-hifi-stereo-adc-and-max4466-micr.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. @Daniel
My problem is that the simulink is not getting the audio data in real time 
sorry for any confusion but I am new to simulink

Comment: If it is not getting real time auto, what do you get instead? Delayed audio or no audio?

Comment: @Daniel I'm not getting audio at all